# 'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetFromJsonAsync'

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I created a new **Blazor**  app and I want to access a URL through  **HttpClient**
I faced this error

> 'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetFromJsonAsync' and
> no accessible extension method 'GetFromJsonAsync' accepting a first
> argument of type 'HttpClient' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?) [BlazorApp]csharp(CS1061) ,

this is my code

```
 @inject HttpClient Http
    <h1>@name</h1>
    @code {
        private string name;
    
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            name = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<string>("api/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added `using System.Net.Http.Json;`? `GetFromJsonAsync` is an extension method, not part of `HttpClient` itself.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - post it as an answer, with a link to the docs page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add the following using directive:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;
```

[`GetFromJsonAsync` is an extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync), not part of `HttpClient` itself.

Comment: its works 
also `Http.GetAsync("/api").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` can be used

Comment: @esamaldinelzain - that is a very bad alternative. Always avoid `.Result`

Answer (score -2):

I recently faced the same issue. Even after adding the directive "using System.Net.Http.Json;" It still generate the error message.

More acurately, what eventually resolved my issue was to add the following additional directive to the top of the page:

@inject HttpClient HttpClient

and the problem was resolved.